# Power BI/ Sorting / Is there anyway to sort multiple visuals based on a shared measure?

Tags: sorting, powerbi

I have multiple visuals based on the same measures, but I'd like to be able to sort both of them the same way with a one-click. So, say YTD sales is defaults, then I could hit a button and re-sort the visuals by avg sale amout, etc.

This is something I could do with a macro in excel, but I've not been able to find a way in PowerBI.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it!
Probably you can create an additional measure with a RANKX and put sorting on it. The main concept is to use the SWITCH function based on a slicer from a not-connected table. For example, we can create a table with labels "YTD Sale", "AVG", "By category" etc.

This new measure should looks like:

```
MeasureForSort = 
var __WhatToSort = SWITCH(TRUE(),
SELECTEDVALUE (AdditionalTable[Lable]) = "AVG", [AVGmeasure],
SELECTEDVALUE (AdditionalTable[Lable]) = "YTD Sale", [YTD Salemeasure],
[SomeElseHere])
var __Sorting = RANKX(MainTable, __WhatToSort, __WhatToSort , DESC)

return __Sorting
```

So, you can add this measure to your visualization and add sort on it. One-click from the slicer should re-sort every widget.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking along these lines (I believe there is an INDEX feature in DAX). But another resource told me using Bookmarks was the way to go.